# Open File behaviour with Internet Explorer 6 and 8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-6

Is there a different behaviour between IE6 and IE8 how they open a file? I've a file on a network drive or local drive which I'd like to open with (standard) JavaScript.

However, IE6 does open (e.g.) a text file within a browser and IE8 does open the text file in notepad. I do need IE8's behaviour in both browser versions. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to open a text file in a browser if you want to edit it anyway? Just open Notepad and choose the file you want to edit.

Comment: Can you post the javascript you've attempted?

Comment: Sure. I'm using window.open(...) to open the file. I can't use location.href=... because file can have any file format. It even can be a HTML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't control the default behavior for other users, it depends on their settings.

For instance in IE8, I can go to:

Tools > Internet Settings > Internet Programs > Set Programs

Which opens up a Windows dialog that allows me to control default behavior.

When you say:

> I do need IE8's behaviour in both
>   browser versions.

Is this for you, or your users? If it's for your users, you can forget about it - there's no way you hijack their settings, or even tell if they even have notepad installed. If it's for you, then just edit your settings.

Comment: You're right and IE6 and IE8 handle this different. Thank you for your help!